# Convert date string to another format date string in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a dataframe that has two columns named `created_at` and `updated_at` which are date strings with format `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000`. I need them to be converted to `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`. I have tried the following things but none works:

```
data[['created_at', 'updated_at']] = pd.to_datetime(
                data[['created_at', 'updated_at']], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

data[['created_at', 'updated_at']] = data[['created_at', 'updated_at']].apply(
                lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

data[['created_at', 'updated_at']] = pd.to_datetime(
                data[['created_at', 'updated_at']], infer_datetime_format=True, utc=True)
```

How could I solve it? Thanks

Comment: are you sure you want to use a literal `+0000` in the format code? this will get you into trouble in case the UTC offset changes... In general, I think you don't need a format code here at all; pandas will auto-detect ISO8601 just fine.

Comment: I don't want to use +0000. I get this time format and I have to upload it to Redshift, so nothing to do there

Comment: to clarify: from your code sample, I'd assume only your input contains a UTC offset in the form of `+-xxxx`. Do you want the *output* to have that as well?

Comment: You assumed right. In the output I just want the format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'. jezrael answer is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
f = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, utc=True).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
data[['created_at', 'updated_at']] = data[['created_at', 'updated_at']].apply(f)
```